# What is the minimum depth / base depth of a recursive function, 0 or 1?

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion, methods

What is the minimum depth of a recursive function? That is, if a recursive function is called, but it immediately goes to the base case, then is it a recursive depth of 0 or 1?

Comment: This seems subjective, although I would start counting at 1.

Comment: It's not subjective when you have to choose a right answer.

Comment: I dodn't think there's a right or wrong here. There's no universal truth in this case.

Comment: So you're telling me that it is impossible to correctly answer this question on a test?

Comment: @AaronFranke it's like some programming languages have 0-based array indexes while others are 1-based. Neither is wrong. One could suggest that if a function does not recur, it has not incremented the depth, and therefore has a recursion depth of 0, the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum). Another could suggest that a function that does not recur still uses 1 stack frame, so return a base recursion depth of 1. Neither is wrong. Your teacher can choose whatever answer he/she wishes to be correct.

Comment: @AaronFranke no, I'm saying either might be correct given the circumstance. We're not talking about a some kind of standard here. If your class heavily focused on specific books or learning material I'd try to see what convention these use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As argued in the comments, in general this can be 0 or 1, but must always rely on some definition. If this is a possible question for you course then we should assume that there is a correct answer.

If this is not stated in you script at some point it should be possible find a related definition such that you can follow a correct answer from there, for example: The recursive function can be seen as a tree (recursion tree). Assuming you have a tree and its height defined in your class then you can follow from there. Let T be a tree that only contains one node, the root node. What is the height of T? Zero or one, it can be defined either way. This height would also be the minimum depth of you recursive function.

Comment: If you're curious, I did find out after the test that the answer they wanted was zero. Good answer and discussion though, there are cases for both.